# Header and Footer Spacing for Bookdown PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm trying to help someone with Latex but have been out of touch and need some help. They need a header with their company logo and chapter name. And a footer with website address etc. I have been able to get the most of it, but text for the page is too close to Header and Footer. Position of Header and Footer is perfect and I would like to retain that. But I would like to push the starting of the text little down and ending of the text little up.

This is the code I'm using:

````
---
title: "CBSE 8 Math Sample Papers"
author: "CodingHero"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
geometry: left=3cm, right=3cm, tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm, top= 2cm,

header-includes:
     \usepackage{fancyhdr}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
        \lhead{\includegraphics[width = 100pt]{Logo.png}}
        \chead{}
        \lfoot{https://codinghero.ai}
        \cfoot{\thepage}
        \rfoot{learn@codinghero.ai}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
               \markboth{#1}{}}
````

Output looks like this:
[image: Would like to push the starting of the text down]

[image: Would like to push the ending of the text up]

Comment: Can you show the intermedia .tex file?

Comment: There is no such file. I'm using Bookdown package

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=0.5in, headsep=0.5in, footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
```

If you want to have a 1-inch margin on all sides and a 0.5 inch space between the header/footer and the text area.

Comment: and also 0.5 inch for header height